# how to make a difference between server port number and client port number?

Tags: networking, tcp

I would like to know what is the interval ports number for servers and for clients. I have a list of port numbers and I need to separate clients and servers.

Comment: You have just a list of number, or there is some more context?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot separate separate servers from clients solely based on the port number.

For example,

```
my_addr1.sin_family = AF_INET; 
my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
my_addr1.sin_port = htons(12010); 
my_addr1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.11.12.13"); 
if (bind(client, (struct sockaddr*) &my_addr1, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == 0) 
    printf("Binded Correctly\n"); 
else
    printf("Unable to bind\n");
```

will bind your client explicitly to port 12010 (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explicitly-assigning-port-number-client-socket/ for a complete demo). The same goes for servers: you can easily have your server listen to some specific TCP (or UDP) port.

Luckily, there are a number of well known ports, kept by IANA (Internet Assigned Number Authority) in the Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry. Any well-thinking organization should (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) respect these assignments. But there is no guarantee, and 'client' and 'server' may be different from your expectation (see f.e. 123: NTP).

Likewise, clients that behave nicely, in general use ephemeral port numbers. These are high port numbers which are handed out by the OS when a program asks for an available port. To complicate things: ephemeral port differ per OS:

```
OS             from         to       comment
AIX            32768        65535
BSD            49152        65535
Slackware      32768        60999    cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
Windows        5000         65534    may differ per version.
```

To make things worse, there is `portmapper`, which, more or less dynamically, assigns port numbers to servers (in general 100001 and up). But outside NFS it is rarely used.

So, you can make a decent assumption, based on IANA's well known port numbers and the ephemeral port ranges from your OS-s, but there is no guarantee that it is correct.

On Linux, use `sudo netstat -lpe` to see a list of servers. On other OSes see the man page or documentation for `netstat` for the appropriate flags.